# Measuring Distance between Camera and Object in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm working on a project where I am trying to calculate the distance and angle of a small LED light from a single camera. I'm struggling to find an answer to this. The primary inputs of the project need to be size and distance from intensity.

As I don't know how to do this, I have tried some experiments of using coloured objects - converting from `GBR` to `HSV`. I know the height and width of my object and I know the initial distance from the camera. I used a 15cm ruler as a guide. I've used masks to extract the expected colour which does work. However, I don't know how to further this to extract the distance in real-time and update the distance value as the object is moving on camera.

Comment: This sounds very experimental even outside of the scope of software development. Even if you apply the correct formulas and algorithm the physical and internal properties of the camera are going to make it really hard. For example the compression will create very different white values depending on how the light is positioned between pixels and compression blocks even if you are able to deactivate features like light adaption and any "optimization" from the firmware.

Comment: Which physical and internal properties are you referring to? The OP uses a (as far as I understand) standard pinhole camera.

Comment: if you use a pattern of LEDs of known shape, you can use solvePnp to get the object pose (position and rotation) if you know the camera model (intrinsics and lens distortion). For a single measurement point the 3D position is ambiguous (could be either a big/bright light far away from the camera or a small light close to the camera).

Comment: But how do you want to measure the distance? SolvePnP is used for pose estimation not distance estimation.

Answer (score -1):

The question is unclear to me. Which kind of intensity do you refer to? Light intensity of the LED?
Anyway, if you want to calculate the distance of an object from a single camera then this is called "monocular depth estimation". You can google it. Generally, calculating the depth from a single camera is not possible.
Except:

1. You use machine learning algorithms like https://keras.io/examples/vision/depth_estimation/
2. You use time of flight hardware like RADAR, LIDAR, Sonar
3. You know the shape of your objects, you can do some distance calculations. Here is a tutorial: https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/

Comment: This sounds more like a lengthy comment than an answer.

Comment: I will improve my answer as soon as the OP gets more clear about what she is doing.